# ActiveX events in Python

Tags: python, activex

I am working on a project where a existing backend uses ActiveX libraries. I need to program an extension in Python for this project and I think is necessary to use COM objects from a proprietary library. I would like to know if it is possible to capture ActiveX events from Python

My operating system is Windows and the backend is written in Visual Basic.

Can you provide some guidance on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [answer by luc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1067842/3645757)

1) Install [pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) by using pip (pip install pywin32)

2) Run makepy (C:...\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client)
this will allow you to select the relevant ActiveX and create a python wrapper for it

3) Use the wrapper (created at step 2) in your code (see [luc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1067842/3645757) for an excel example) or check [this link](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html)