# How to tell the printer to print grayscale or colored content

Tags: winapi, win32com, python-3.7

I have this line of codes that will tell the printer to print a document. But it will only print colored content.

```
word = Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.Documents.Open(self.filePath)
word.ActiveDocument.PrintOut()
word.ActiveDocument.Close()
word.Quit()
```

What I want is to tell the printer to print grayscale content. Is there any possible solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Q: How to tell the printer to print grayscale or colored content?

- **Short Answer:**:

  You have to talk to the relevant printer driver, which is completely platform- and API-specific.
- **Longer Answer:**

  The snippet you showed, `word = Dispatch("Word.Application")`, is using a Python wrapper to Microsoft [Com/ActiveX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065844/).  Specifically, to the MS-Word COM/ActiveX component (which was presumably registered on your PC when you installed MS-Word).

  So all you have to do is look at the options provided by "Word.Application":

  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.printout

Be advised, you might also have to play around with "Printer Device Settings", for example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.printer