# PyQt5 wrapper for ActiveX object instead of WX wrapper

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt5, activex

I'm trying to get a USB camera to display a live video feed to a PyQt5 application. I have working code for a wx wrapper but I need this to work in PyQt5. After many searches I just can't find the right syntax.

Here's the working WX code:

```
import wx
from wx.lib.activexwrapper import MakeActiveXClass
from win32com.client import gencache

class mainFrm( wx.Frame ):
    def __init__( self, *args, **kwds ):
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__( self, *args, **kwds )

        self.dcamModule = gencache.EnsureModule( '{6B9BD678-9710-44D9-9282-A088094E4216}', 0, 1, 0 )       
        dcamClass = MakeActiveXClass( self.dcamModule.ActiveGeni, eventObj = self )
        self.camera = dcamClass( self, -1 )

        self.camera.SetSize(( 752, 480 ))
        self.SetClientSize( ( 752, 480 ))

        self.camera.Acquire = True 
        self.camera.Display = True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI = wx.PySimpleApp( 0 )
    frame_1 = mainFrm( None, -1, "" )
    GUI.SetTopWindow( frame_1 )
    frame_1.Show()
    GUI.MainLoop()
```

When I debug what is happening this is what I get as the objects are built:

```
print(self.dcamModule)
<module 'win32com.gen_py.6B9BD678-9710-44D9-9282-A088094E4216x0x1x0' from '...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\3\\gen_py\\3.5\\6B9BD678-9710-44D9-9282-A088094E4216x0x1x0.py'>

print(dcamClass)
<class 'wx.lib.activexwrapper.AXControl_ActiveGeni'>

print(self.camera)
<win32com.gen_py.None.AXControl_ActiveGeni>
```

Here is the PyQt5 that I've tried. Is doesn't give an error but it doesn't start the camera either:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QAxContainer import QAxWidget

qtCreatorFile = "ui\\camera_form.ui"
LandingPageUI, LandingPageBase = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class cameraForm(LandingPageBase, LandingPageUI):

    def __init__(self,  parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        LandingPageBase.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.ocx = QAxWidget("'{6B9BD678-9710-44D9-9282-A088094E4216}', 0, 1, 0 ")
#Is there something else to do here?
        self.ocx.Acquire = True
        self.ocx.Display = True
        self.axWidget = self.ocx     #axWidget is the QaXWidget on the form


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication.instance() 
    if not app: 
         app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = cameraForm()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I try the PyQt version this is what I get when debugging:

```
print(self.axWidget)
<PyQt5.QAxContainer.QAxWidget object at 0x036C4C60>
```

It seems that the MakeActiveXClass step for wx is doing something that isn't done with PyQt but I can't figure out what it should be instead.

Here are some resources that I've referenced so far:

[win32.Dispatch vs win32.gencache in Python. What are the pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127959/win32-dispatch-vs-win32-gencache-in-python-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)

[What can you do with COM/ActiveX in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065844/what-can-you-do-with-com-activex-in-python)

I've tried QCamera as well but it does not recognize the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making `self.axWidget = self.ocx` does not cause `self.ocx` to replace `self.axWidget` in the window, the solution is to use `self.axWidget`  by setting the control using the [setControl()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaxbase.html#control-prop) method:

```py
class cameraForm(LandingPageBase, LandingPageUI):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(cameraForm, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.axWidget.setControl("{6B9BD678-9710-44D9-9282-A088094E4216}")
        self.axWidget.setProperty("Acquire", True)
        self.axWidget.setProperty("Display", True)
```

<sup>(Code not tested)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for answering! There must be multiple problems with my code because that didn't solve it. See my edit with debug output.

Comment: @jshort I don't understand why you think debug in Wx and Qt should be similar. On the other hand what is the output of `self.axWidget.generateDocumentation()`?

Comment: @jshort try changing `self.axWidget.setProperty("Acquire", True)` to `self.axWidget.dynamicCall("Acquire", True)` and `self.axWidget.setProperty("Display", True) ` to `self.axWidget.dynamicCall("Display", True)`

Comment: generateDocumentation() didn't produce anything and it wasn't picky about the dynamicCall but you were right, of course, about how to use setControl. Never did get it to work with the CLSID though

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by finding the right call in the setControl. Not sure why the CLSID didn't work but this did:

```
    self.axWidget.setControl("ActiveGeni.ActiveGeni")
```

I'm excited to use this feature in Qt but I'm still not sure how to see what other activeX I can call. For example I could use "Microsoft Web Browser" and load a PDF but not "Adobe PDF Reader". How do I see what is available?